# Output duplicates with matching column

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, duplicates, multiple-columns

So for example I have the following information in an Excel sheet or Google Sheets:

Column 1  ...   Number 1       ............ Column 2 ....    Number 2
A1    ..............       N1.........................  B1................P1
A2    ..............         N2  .........................A1................P2
A3    ..............         N3  .........................B3................P3
A4    ..............         N4  .........................B4................P4
A5    ..............         N5 .........................A4................P5

Now I want to be able to compare Column 1 with Column 2 and, when there's a duplicate, have it output to a new column with both matching numbers. So the output should be:

Duplicates....Number 1.....Number 2
A1 ...............N1.................P2
A4 ...............N4.................P5

I've tried multiple functions on both Excel and Google Sheets, and I did find myself being able to find duplicates, but I am not able to get both correlated numbers to a new output.

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP() to pull numbers from Number1 to a new column next to Number2, then sort and copy the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as required but might serve. Assuming `Column 1` is in A1:

in E2: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,1,0)),"",B2)`
in F2: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,0))`

with both copied down to suit.